# How does 'Trim Curve' node evaluate the order of splines?

Tags: geometry-nodes, path, splines

I'm animating trimming of Curves with Geo nodes. My setup looks something like this.
I'm delaying the start of the animation for multiple curves.
I don't know how to control the order in which the paths will be trimmed.
I guess the "Trim paths" node trims these paths according to their Index number (in pink)? If so - can I rearrange this order?

I'd like the paths to be trimmed based on their X position. The ones most to the left should trim first, and the ones most to the right - last. How would you go about that?

Cheers

[image]